# Por qual motivo ainda não temos ícones nas tags?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso

Lá no SOen percebemos que algumas tags mais populares possui alguns ícones indicativos. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [firebase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase) [google-cloud-messaging](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-messaging)

Apesar de não ser tão relevante em relação as perguntas e respostas, mais uma questão de aparência, mas por qual motivo ainda não temos ícones nas tags?

Comment: É duplicada essa pergunta

Comment: Relacionada: [Adicionar ícones/imagens em tags](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2611/4808)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters quando eu escrevi o título, não apareceu nada, então achei que não haveria outra questão assim.

Comment: @AckLay duplicar não é problema. Ela serve de link para outras.